# Rails configurations with mailers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailer

i am having troubles using the rails configuration adress in the mailer. I use the newest ruby and rails versions and want to add a mail adress from the configurations. 
i am using the folling code in the mailer file:

```
 mail(to: Rails.configuration.email.sales , subject: 'Contact through jobs page')
```

on the development.rb page i am using this code:

```
  config.email.sales = 'sales@domain.com'
```

i dont understand why this isnt working. 
Would be great if you can help me. Thanks

Comment: You should use a config yml file for that. The way you like to realize this, is not possible in my opinion.

Comment: Have you tried putting a normal email instead of Rails.configuration.email.sales

Comment: when i use a string like 
mail(to: 'sales@domain' , subject: 'Contact through jobs page')
its working great

Comment: "Newest" is a vague term i would recommend adding specifics becuase if someone comes across this later it will be more beneficial to them to know what version "newest" refers to.

Answer (score 1):

Since you add that into development.rb that, you can try with something like:

```
mail(to: YourApplication::Application.config.email.sales,, subject: 'Contact through jobs page')
```

That will return 'sales@domain.com', if you have that config.email.sales properly working :).